# 2010 MacBook A1342 crashing when booting UEFI Windows if GPU drivers are loaded

Tags: windows-10, macbook, nvidia-geforce

I have a white polycarbonate 2010 MacBook with the GeForce 320M graphics. I've been trying to install Windows 10 for some time, and while I am able to install and navigate using the fallback GPU drivers, the system will bootloop if I try to install proper Nvidia/Apple provided drivers for the 320M. This seems to be a common issue with these Tesla based Macs, and the fix supposedly is with changing PCI register values like so: (https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=162289&p=4)

`mm 0017003E -PCI 8`
`mm 02000004 -PCI 7`

I've tried to do this in UEFI shell before booting (I have OpenCore installed, which has a built in EFI shell) and then manually booting bootmgfw.efi, but it only results in a black screen. I have verified that these are the right PCI addresses through `pci -b` in UEFI shell, where 1700 is shown as the bridge and 0002 is the graphics card. There is another bridge at 1500, but if I change it the system boots without the GPU present in device manager (so no acceleration).
If anybody has encountered a similar problem with their 2010 MacBook, please tell me if you've found a fix. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the latest supported drivers? v. 342.01 according to Nvidia.

Comment: I've tried official Bootcamp drivers, Windows Update drivers, and 342 from NVIDIA. All have the same problem.

Comment: Then probably the hardware is defective, not surprising given the age.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a known problem with the way Apple implemented the 320M in UEFI mode. The hardware itself is not defective; macOS works without issues and Linux works if I boot it through MBR.

Comment: Neither Win10 nor BootCamp supports any hardware that old. The Mac itself isn't supported, & neither is the GPU. When Win10 was released, some machines got a hasty one-off driver, but in the last 5 years they've all been quietly dropped. Last driver for the 320M was 2016.

Comment: Here to report that the 320M works properly after I installed Windows through MBR (had to boot off a DVD I burned). Hybrid MBR had to be made with gdisk so Windows could install this way. So the hardware evidently isn't defective, nor unsupported in Windows 11, but Apple's UEFI vBIOS implementation is bugged.

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/504490016735494145/897652972996145182/unknown.png

Comment: The hardware is most definitely unsupported in Win 11. [Win 11's baseline support is "last 3 years" for hardware, though people are finding ways round that] It was already unsupported in current Win 10, though it had basic support in 2015. idk what hoops you had to jump through to get WIn 11 to ignore even the TPM requirement. I'm glad you got it working anyway.